# Android studio and 'trust project' problem

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

When I open any project or create a new project, ide shows the trust project option but it's not working
and Gradle doesn't sync, and trust project sync still available on top of the page

Answer (score 1):

### You need to clean up the `trusted-paths.xml`

It's located in the configuration directory of Android Studio (for MacOS)

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2021.2/options
```

1. Quit Android Studio
2. Find the file `trusted-paths.xml` and clean up and save it.
3. Open Android Studio and your project

Comment: for Windows or Linux OS, cleaning up the trusted-paths.xml should solve the problem